# How to model a miniature elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

For educational purposes I would need to work on an elliptic curve that has a small field, but holds the safety futures of a real curve. Is that possible to have such a curve!?

For example for the curve of secp256k1, is that possible to find small $P$, $N$ and $G$ so that the mini curve does still have safety features of the real curve? By safety features I mean those features that come from the difficulty of solving the discrete logarithm problem. Of course I know that a curve with a small field is vulnerable through brute-force attacks.

To do so, first I read about properties of the prime $P$. It seems that it is a SAFE prime which is equal to $3 \bmod 4$. If I search for a small prime with the same two properties am I getting the correct mini curve?

How are $G$ and $N$ decided then?

I need a curve that lets me do point manipulations (adding, doubling, halving,...)  with plotable easy-to-work-with integers, not those 78-digits of secp256k1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curve parameters include:

$p$: The prime modulus of the underlying field

$a$ and $b$: These are used in the curve equation, $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$

$G$: a point on the curve that generates a subgroup

$n$: the order (number of points) of that subgroup

Once you have decided on your $p$, the process is basically try different curve parameters and a [point-counting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_points_on_elliptic_curves) to find a curve with a large, prime order subgroup.

You can do this all automatically using [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/)

Here is a script that will generate a curve for you with the given bit size: https://github.com/brichard19/ecdl/blob/master/scripts/gencurve.sage

Comment: How is p decided!? I assume it should be A safe prime which is $p=3 mod 4$. Anything more to consider?!

Comment: @user13741, the sage script defines the prime according to the required bits and not what the OP wanted which is, given a field, to find a good EC

Answer (score 1):

> I would need to work on an elliptic curve that has a small field, but holds the safety futures of a real curve. Is that possible to have such a curve!?

No, it is not possible. A necessary condition for a curve to be "safe" is that it has enough points on it. But the number of points is closely correlated to the size of the base field; namely if the size of the base field is $q$ then the curve will have between $q +1  \pm 2 \cdot \sqrt q$ points (this is the so-called [Hasse bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves)).

> By safety features I mean those features that come from the difficulty of solving the discrete logarithm problem. Of course I know that a curve with a small field is vulnerable through brute-force attacks.

So you want a curve where solving the discrete log is difficult even though it is vulnerable to brute-force attacks. This makes no sense. A brute-force attack is just one way of solving the discrete log problem; if such an attack can be done on a curve, then the curve does not have "those features that come from the difficulty of solving the discrete logarithm problem".

Comment: I do not want a safe curve. I need a model curve.

Comment: @PouJa Make up your mind. Do you want "safety features", or do you not?

Comment: I do not want a safe curve. I want a curve on which I can explain with easy to show small numbers that this elliptic curve gives an irreversible public key unless we have to check all possible private keys.